# Get module config settings or params

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I'm using Yii 1, And am trying to get the module settings set in my `config/main.php` that look like this

```
'modules' => array (
                'products' => array(
                    'countries' => array('sg', 'th'),
                 )
),
```

This code works in my the non `products` controllers

```
Yii::app()->controller->getModule('Products')->countries;
```

But when i add into my custom URL class it doesn't. Here is part of my class

```
class RegionUrlRule extends CBaseUrlRule
{
    public $connectionID = 'db';

    private $countryArray;

    
    public function __construct() {

        //get list of allowed countries
        $this->countryArray = Yii::app()->controller->getModule('Products')->countries;
    }
    
    public function createUrl($manager,$route,$params,$ampersand)
    {
        .........
    }

    .........

}
```

On this, i get this error

```
Call to a member function getModule() on null
```

and when i use this

```
Yii::app()->getModule('Products')->countries;
```

i get nothing, and no error

How do i fix this? Thanks

Comment: define nothing (*"i get nothing, and no error"*), dump the value for `Yii::app()->getModule('Products')->countries;`, is it null or an empty array?

Comment: When I `print_r(); die;` its empty. Doesn't display anything on my browser.

Comment: Use [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) instead of `print_r();` Also: you use `'Products'`, but in your definition array you use `'products'`. Maybe getModule is case sensitive?

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal thanks! it is case sensitive. i missed that.